# Assigning two restrict qualified pointers to the same data in C11?

Tags: c, pointers, c11, restrict

I have been working a lot with restrict qualified pointers, and I thought of something that, although I wouldn't do it, the fact that it seems to be standard compliant makes me question whether there is something I am missing in my understanding of the standard. In particular, as far as I can tell, one could, in a standard compliant way, get two restrict qualified pointers pointing to the same block of data. Consider the following example.

```
int* restrict p = (int[2]){0,0};
int* restrict* x = (int* restrict*)(int*[1]){p};
**x = 1;
p[1] = 2;
```

I assign an `int*` that is not restrict qualified to `p`, so that does not violate the portion of the standard relating to assigning restrict qualified pointers to each other, 6.7.3.1 paragraph 4. Here is the whole of 6.7.3.1, for reference.

> 6.7.3.1 Formal definition of restrict
>
> 1 Let D be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a means of designating an
>   object P as a restrict-qualified pointer to type T.
>
> 2 If D appears inside a block and does not have storage class extern, let B denote the
>   block. If D appears in the list of parameter declarations of a function definition, let B
>   denote the associated block. Otherwise, let B denote the block of main (or the block of
>   whatever function is called at program startup in a freestanding environment).
>
> 3 In what follows, a pointer expression E is said to be based on object P if (at some
>   sequence point in the execution of B prior to the evaluation of E) modifying P to point to
>   a copy of the array object into which it formerly pointed would change the value of E. 137)
>   Note that ‘‘based’’ is defined only for expressions with pointer types.
>
> 4 During each execution of B, let L be any lvalue that has &L based on P. If L is used to
>   access the value of the object X that it designates, and X is also modified (by any means),
>   then the following requirements apply: T shall not be const-qualified. Every other lvalue
>   used to access the value of X shall also have its address based on P. Every access that
>   modifies X shall be considered also to modify P, for the purposes of this subclause. If P
>   is assigned the value of a pointer expression E that is based on another restricted pointer
>   object P2, associated with block B2, then either the execution of B2 shall begin before
>   the execution of B, or the execution of B2 shall end prior to the assignment. If these
>   requirements are not met, then the behavior is undefined.
>
> 5 Here an execution of B means that portion of the execution of the program that would
>   correspond to the lifetime of an object with scalar type and automatic storage duration
>   associated with B.
>
> 6 A translator is free to ignore any or all aliasing implications of uses of restrict.

So, then I cast a pointer to an unqualified type to a pointer to a qualified version of that type, allowed under 6.3.2.3 paragraph 2:

> For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to
>   the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers
>   shall compare equal.

I then store this converted pointer to a new object, `x`. Paragraph 4 seems to not cover this, because `x` is not being assigned from an expression based on an object P that is designated through a declaration D of an ordinary identifier (there is no such declaration relating to the object from which `x` is assigned).

Now `*x` is an object with a restrict qualified effective type, and it is based on p. Modifying one element of the array with both pointers would violate the condition that only expressions based on `*x` can modify any object that is ever modified by an expression based on `*x`, so it is hard to see how you can get things too out of hand like this.

Nonetheless, there is a less contrived situation I am dealing with (that would be too long for a question here), where anything disallowing this might be relevant to what I am doing.

So, in short, my question is:

- Is the above code I gave standard compliant in C11?

Comment: You're lying to the compiler, so it will get its own back on you by doing what you don't expect.  You said the pointers are restricted, so it believes you.  That you lied isn't the compiler's problem — it is your problem.  Assume you will get the wrong answer, somehow, somewhen.

Comment: But my question is that it appears I am not lying. Maybe I am wrong in that conclusion, but that is why I am asking. The definition of restrict is not "it has its own data", that would not be precise enough. The restrict promise iis a formal agreement specifically outlined in the standard, and like I say in the question, what I am doing here seems to be in keeping with that formal promise.

Comment: OK; we'll have to differ.  Do you want me to delete my comment?

Comment: No of course not, I would actually appreciate some details on why you consider this lying to the compiler, if you have the time. I try to outline why I think it is not, and if I am mistaken, and you can tell me how, that would be very helpful.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, you said "there will be no alias for the data pointed at by `p` anywhere in the current block of code".  You then create a pointer `x` which (via double indirection) refers to the same data.  Therefore, IMO, you are not telling the truth to the compiler — the data pointed at by `p` can be accessed by other means than just `p` in this block of code.  I'm not sure how to parse the wording of the standard into handling that, but I believe that's a reasonable approximation to what the declarations say.

Comment: Thanks for expounding. It seems to me that the only clause in the standard that deals with that issue in relation to assigning values to pointers is there in paragraph 4. And in that paragraph it specifically requires that the source of the value being assigned be the value of a restrict qualified object accessible through an ordinary identifier. The other language seems to relate to the pointed to data, rather than the values of pointer objects. So, it seems my code gets around all the language, and that is a red flag to me, saying I should verify I am understanding things correctly.

Comment: Does §6.7.3 ¶8 help — _An object that is accessed through a restrict-qualified pointer has a special association
with that pointer. This association, defined in 6.7.3.1 below, requires that all accesses to
that object use, directly or indirectly, the value of that particular pointer.135) The intended
use of the restrict qualifier (like the register storage class) is to promote
optimization, and deleting all instances of the qualifier from all preprocessing translation
units composing a conforming program does not change its meaning (i.e., observable
behavior)._ — the 'all accesses' bit?

Comment: Yes, that is why I say that one could not modify any one element with both pointers. However, one could read any object with both pointers, if that object is not modified anywhere. And any object could be accessed freely by one pointer if it is left alone by the other. So there would be restrictions. However, it does seem the pointers could be assigned their values as I have done.

Comment: I think that because `x` has a pointer to a copy of `p`, it is not accessing the data via the pointer `p`.  If you had something like `int * restrict * x = &p;`, then you'd be accessing the data via `p` indirectly.  I think that the ¶8 I quoted is key to the understanding — but I'm willing to concede I could be wrong.

Comment: However, it seems that relation is on an object by object basis. And it does not kick in for an object, unless that object is modified somewhere. So two restrict pointers can point to the same data, if the data is not modified. And that is what I am doing here. There is however, a second restriction on assigning the value of one restrict pointer to another - this restriction seems quite separate than that special relation to pointed to objects. It is this second restriction that I think the above gets around, seeming to violate the intent of the second restriction without breaking any rules.

Comment: To clarify, I respect the relation by only modifying an element with one pointer if I don't access it with another. Other elements could be read by both pointers.

Comment: Arrays are objects; all accesses to all elements of the array that `p` points at should go through `p`, directly or indirectly.  The accesses via `x` do not go through `p` (they use a copy of `p`).  Note that 'access' includes read and write.  C standard ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §3 Definitions — §3.1 
_**access**
〈execution-time action〉 to read or modify the value of an object.
NOTE 1 Where only one of these two actions is meant, ‘‘read’’ or ‘‘modify’’ is used.
NOTE 2 ‘‘Modify’’ includes the case where the new value being stored is the same as the previous value._

Comment: Yes arrays are objects, but the pointers are used to access int objects, not arrays of ints. So, even if the space is initially put on the stack as an array, the object accessed by the restrict pointer is not an array, it is an int. And access includes read and write, but the restriction on access only applies to the access of objects that are at some point modified. So, by my understanding, any one element can either be read by both pointers, or read and modified by one of them only. But each element individually can be treated one way, while its neighbors are treated another way.

Comment: You'll have to wait for a C guru to assist us — I can go no further.

Comment: My guess is that you can do this, based on Example 1 following section 6.7.3.1: _The file scope declarations ... assert that if an object is accessed using `a`, `b`, or `c`, and that object is modified anywhere in the program, then it is never accessed using either of the other two._ In your case, you access the first object in the array with `x` first, so use of `p[0]` or `*p` following that would be invalid. However, you modify `p[1]`, which was not modified and therefore yields defined behavior. Of course this means you cannot use `(*x)[1]`.

Comment: Looking again, it seems you might trigger undefined behavior: `x[0]` is initialized to `p` in the same block, and both are `restrict`-qualified, meaning the _either the execution B2 shall begin before the execution of B, or the execution of B2 shall end prior to the assignment_ clause is not satisfied. Example 11 of section 6.7.3.1 is basically the same as your example code. If you wrapped the declaration of `x` and assignment to `**x` in a nested block, then you'd no longer exhibit the undefined behavior. You also could just initialize `x` to `&p` as this would mean `p` is used.

Comment: But what seems to get around that is the condition preceding what you quoted: if P is assigned the value of some P2 that is accessible as a restrict qualified pointer by means of some other ordinary identifier - there is no ordinary identifier satisfying this property, as there is no ordinary identifier at all giving access to the object from which the assignment takes place.

Comment: @Kyle Hmm, I don't see anything that states it must be an ordinary identifier, and you didn't quote it either. It merely states that an expression based on a `restrict`-qualified pointer may only be assigned to another `restrict`-qualified pointer under certain conditions pertaining to the order of execution of the blocks in which the pointers are declared. In your case, the restricted pointer `x[0]` is initialized to the restricted pointer expression `p` within the same block, so there is a violation.

Comment: If you altered your code to `int *restrict *x = &p;` then there wouldn't be a violation because `x` itself is not `restrict`-qualified. The fact that you initialize an array of `restrict`-qualified pointers with a `restrict`-qualified pointer in the same block is your problem. To use the array method, you'd need to use `int *restrict p = (int[2]){0,0}; { int *restrict *x = (int *[1]){p}; **x = 1; } p[1] = 2;` since the execution of block B2 (anything with `x`) ends before the execution of block B (anything with `p`).

Comment: The requirement of an ordinary identifier is paragraph 1 in the section I quoted. The requirement on pointer assignments relates to "another restricted pointer object P2, associated with block B2", which implies the same restrictions as are in place for P and B, which implies paragraph 1 is in force, which implies the need for an ordinary identifier.

Comment: I do not initialize an array of restrict qualified pointers, so there is no problem there either. I initialize an array of unqualified pointers. I convert a pointer to the first element to a pointer to a restrict qualified version of the first element, and I gave the paragraph that justifies the conversion.

Comment: Well, I'm unfortunately at a loss as well. You have made valid points, so I can't really be certain either way. If you don't receive any satisfactory answers and you still aren't sure if the code is correct yourself, you might try asking on the comp.lang.c newsgroup. I wouldn't expect an answer right away, though, since a lot of discussion usually occurs first.

Comment: OK, thanks for that reference, as well as the discussion. I probably will do that if nothing happens here in the near future. I have a much less trivial situation where correctness stands or falls together with correctness of this little example, I would think, so that is very helpful.